# How do I generate N equispaced points around the contour of an ellipse?

Tags: geometry

Let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be the lengths of the semi-major and semi-minor radii of an ellipse centered at $(0, 0)$, and where the semi-major axis lies along the $x$-axis in our coordinate space.  How can I generate $N$ equispaced points along the contour of the ellipse?

Comment: numerical methods only

Comment: @WillJagy That's actually very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Computing arc lengths of ellipses is tricky, see [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).